# JPanel Organizing Buttons/Images/Etc without GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

So I want to organize my buttons and image without using Gridlayout because it looks horrible.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

and here is the code for the panel, any ideas?:

```
package hi.low;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Card_panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   private final int WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 200;

   private static String[] imageList =  { 
                                            "images/ac.png"
                                        };
   private static int imageNum = -1;

   JButton higher;
   JButton lower;

   public Card_panel()
   {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground (Color.green.darker().darker());

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageList[0]);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
        add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JButton higher = new JButton("Higher");
        higher.setActionCommand("higher");
        higher.addActionListener (this);
        add( higher, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        JButton lower = new JButton("Lower");
        lower.setActionCommand("lower");
        lower.addActionListener (this);
        add( lower, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


   }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String Action;
        Action = e.getActionCommand ();

        if (Action.equals ("higher"))
        {
            System.out.println("User chose higher!");
        }

        if (Action.equals ("lower"))
        {
            System.out.println("User chose lower!");
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should use two layouts (one for the "card", the other for the buttons) and include them in a third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, seen as I can't see any evidence that you are changing it, I will assume that's the layout your panel is using...

Instead, you could use a `GridBagLayout`...

```
public Card_panel()
{

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setBackground (Color.green.darker().darker());

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageList[0]);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    add( label, gbc );

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    JButton higher = new JButton("Higher");
    higher.setActionCommand("higher");
    higher.addActionListener (this);
    add( higher, gbc );

    gbc.gridx++;
    JButton lower = new JButton("Lower");
    lower.setActionCommand("lower");
    lower.addActionListener (this);
    add( lower, gbc );


}
```

You could also use a compound layout, placing the buttons in there own panel, with there own layout and then layout the label and button pane using a different layout